# Derivation of Landau diamagnetism

Tags: statistical-mechanics

In deriving the magnetic susceptibility of free electrons, we need to calculate

$$\chi = \left( \frac{\partial M}{\partial H} \right)_N = - \left( \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial H^2} \right)_N.$$

Here, $F = E- TS $ is the free energy. It should be emphasized that the particle number $N$ is held fixed.

However, in the statistical mechanics book by Landau, he calculated 
$ - \left( \frac{\partial^2 \Omega}{\partial H^2} \right)_\mu $,
where $\Omega = F - \mu N $ is the grand potential. See his equation 59.11 on page 174. The reason seems to be that it is much easier to calculate $\Omega$ as a function of $T, H, \mu$ than $F$ as a function of $T, H, N$.

But, is the calculated quantity the one we really want?

Answer (score 1):

$$-\left(\frac{\partial^2\Omega}{\partial H^2}\right)_\mu=\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial H}\right)_\mu=\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial H}\right)_N+\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial N}\right)_H\left(\frac{\partial N}{\partial H}\right)_\mu$$

In principle, there is a difference between these quantities, at least in ferromagnets (otherwise the magnetization does not depend on $N$, nor $N$ on $H$.   I further suspect that when there is a difference, you typically want the derivative for an open system (constant chemical potential) rather than a closed one (constant number).